# How to possible user subscription in i-contact in android?

Tags: android

I make user subscription in my android application.Also made this user subscription in php example at this link

http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-icontact-20-api-integration-php-example-1925.html

please give me android source code example.